# EntityFramework Add to Many-To-Many

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have a Vacation and a list of Countries. I whish to bind these together using a many-to-many relationship. I have a code-first Vacations model and Countries model. Both the individual tables aswell as the join table are successfully generated.

However, when I try to add a country to a vacation (or vice versa) the join table remains empty. I am able to successfully add the individual vacations aswell as the countries.

**Models**

```
public class Vacations
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int VacationId { get; set; }

    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Countries> Countries { get; set; }


    public Vacations()
    {
        Countries = new List<Countries>();
    }
}



public class Countries
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Vacations> Vacations { get; set; }
    public Countries()
    {
        Vacations = new List<Vacations>();
    }
}




public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("myconn")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Vacations> Vacations { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Countries> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

**Insert the Vacation**

```
            Vacations vacation = database.Vacations.Add(new Vacations
            {
                Name = vacationData.Name,
                Description = vacationData.Description,
            });

            database.SaveChanges();            
            // to make sure the key is in the database to refrence

            foreach (string country in AllMyCountries)
            {
                Countries countries = database.Countries.Add(new Countries
                {
                    CountryName = country
                });
                countries.Vacations.Add(vacation);
                vacation.Countries.Add(countries);
            }

            database.SaveChanges();
```

I have also tried just adding to one entity, and adding more calls to `SaveChanges()` inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem in that your sample code all looks perfectly okay. Infact, I put a quick test together around this code and Entity Framework created the mapping table `vacationscountries` as expected and populated it correctly.

Just on the off-change, can you confirm that you are looking in the mapping table created by Entity Framework and not a custom mapping table? The only reason I mention it is that theres no way (that I know of) to map a many-to-many relationship to a custom junction table using Data Annotations.

If thats not the case, then the next thing I would do is to trace out the sql being generated by Entity Framework - either using your native database tracing tooling (e.g. Sql Profiler), a third party tool like EFProf, or through a logging interceptor ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn469464.aspx ). Hopefully that will give some lower-level insights into the problem.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. My `countriesvacations` join table is generated by ef6 automagicially. I traced out the SQL being generated and ran against the database. I do see the vacation query, and the country query. Hoewever a query creating the relation or inserting something into the join table is absent.

Answer (score 0):

I re-created your Models but made some adjustments that generate the same results. I manually created the junction table `VacationsCountries` with the following code:

```
public class VacationsCountries
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int VacationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vacations Vacation { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Countries Country { get; set; }
}
```

I also added this line of code to the MyContext class:

```
public DbSet<VacationsCountries> VacationsCountries { get; set; }
```

Instead of using:

```
countries.Vacations.Add(vacation);
vacation.Countries.Add(countries);
```

I use:

```
VacationsCountries vc = database.VacationsCountries.Add(new VacationsCountries
{
    Country = countries,
    Vacation = vacation
});
```

and then call `database.SaveChanges();`

I checked the database and the entries were added to the VacationsCountries table.